# Google Tag Manager script Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm attempting to implement [the Google Tag Manager script](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) onto my page but it's throwing an error. I stripped down my html page to the bare-bones:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'm still seeing the following error thrown in the conole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:14:12
    at gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:57
    at Object.Th (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:59)
    at sf (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:31)
    at uk.B (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:90)
    at ag (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:99)
    at jg (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:39)
    at Array.a.push (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:105)
    at Array.<anonymous> (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:105)
    at Lf (gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX:34)
```

[The GA Debugger Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) shows that the script is still "working", i.e. all the proper ga methods are firing. I'm just concerned what this error is.

Note, I also get the same error in Firefox and Safari (the trace looks slightly different but it's the same error):

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tryformurls.test')
    Global Code (Script Element 2:14)
    insertBefore
    (anonymous function) (gtm.js:57:395)
    Th (gtm.js:59:209)
    sf (gtm.js:31)
    (anonymous function) (gtm.js:90:467)
    ag (gtm.js:99:263)
    jg (gtm.js:39:257)
    push (gtm.js:105:388)
    (anonymous function) (gtm.js:105:151)
    Lf (gtm.js:34:198)
    (anonymous function) (gtm.js:106:83)
    Global Code (gtm.js:108)
```

Comment: Do you have any custom HTML tags or JS variables published?

Comment: @mrbubu yes. Turn out this was the issue. Someone wrote custom js that expected a global jQuery object to be on the page. Unfortunately, GTM did not make this apparent from its stack trace.